# Find the order of the following expression as x->0

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Could someone help me find the order of the following expression without using the quotient rule?

$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}$

I expanded the denominator and the numerator but not sure how I get to the answer from here,

$\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{24}+\dots}{2-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\dots}$

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Good work. For $x$ not far from $0$, that gives us the approximation $x^2/4$.

Comment: How does that give you that approximation?

Comment: Well $x^2/2 - x^4/24 + \cdots \approx x^2/2$, and similarly the denominator is $\approx 2$.

Comment: Thank you! How about if I wanted to include more terms?

Comment: There is a standard method for dividing power series, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Dividing_series).